# Плетьми или плетями

Tags: грамматика, склонение, окончания, словоизменение

Они били его плетями/плетьми с такой силы, что после восьмого удара некоторые из присутствующих там дам свалились без чувств.

Какой из вариантов является верным?

Вроде второе, но смущает то, что вместо "властьми", "царьми" и "напастьми" вроде говорят "властями", "царями" и "напастями".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По этому случаю устанавливать правила поздновато. Судя по числу вхождений в Корпус русского языка, уже около 20% пишущих на русском (хоть прозу, хоть стихи) предпочитают форму «плетями».

Выбор примеров для сравнения следовало бы остановить на словах, более близких к «плеть» по звучанию: сеть, клеть, мечеть, лебедь, медведь, заповедь, или может быть: рать, стать, подать, лапоть, ломоть, прихоть…

Формы слов: «клетьми», «сетьми», «ратьми», «заповедьми», «прихотьми» употребляемы были в давние времена и нечасто, например:

«Вы избраны от меня для вечныя славы, чтоб царствовать не на земли, но на небеси; и чтоб получить сей безсмертия венец, надобно победить мир со всеми прихотьми его. [архиепископ Платон (Левшин). Слово в неделю пятую Великаго Поста (1764)]»

Форме «плетьми» (с частотой употребления) повезло больше. Она и в настоящее время доминирует.

Answer (score 2):

Академический орфографический словарь под редакцией Лопатина (Грамота.ру)  указывает: 
плеть, -и, мн. -и, плетей, тв. -ями **(но: бить плетьми)**

Answer (score 2):

Т. Ф. Иванова. Новый орфоэпический словарь русского языка, М., 2008:

**плеть** — *пле́ти... о пле́ти*;
мн. *пле́ти, плете́й, плетя́м, **плетя́ми**, о плетя́х*

Возникла аналогия с ***дверями — дверьми***. Нашла вот такую статью:

*Как известно, в древнерусском языке было не три склонения, а больше. Одни из них в творительном падеже множественного числа требовали окончания –ьми, другие – –ями, –ами. С течением времени слова, относившиеся прежде к разным склонениям, стали относиться к одному и тому же – 3-му. Поэтому у ряда слов, «дверь» в том числе, – допустимыми оказались обе формы, «старая» и «новая».
Это относится и ко многим другим словам, например: «лошадями» и «лошадьми». А вот слово «кость» допустимо в форме «костьми» только в устойчивом выражении «костьми лечь», однако это доказывает, что некогда и оно употреблялось с окончанием -ьми.
Однако принимая решение, как правильно «дверями» или «дверьми», надо иметь в виду, что форма с окончанием -ьми является предпочтительной.*
[Дверями или дверьми](https://obrazovaka.ru/kak-pishetsya/dvermi.html)

Comment: @ Екатерина Каштанова, ваша ссылка не открывается.

Comment: @Серж, благодарю вас. И в самом деле... Посмотрю, как это можно исправить.